# Patterns / design suggestions for permission handling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, design-patterns, permissions

We have a rather complicated system of permission handling in our (ASP.NET web) application. Users can have specific permissions on different kinds of objects, some permissions are even packed into groups / roles that are assigned to users. All in all this ends up in a pretty complicated mess where for determining whether a user can do / see something you have to evaluate many different sources of permissions and this is done somehow on-demand and based on specific situations.

My question is (from a high level point of view) whether there are some suggestions / common design patterns to deal with permission concept in general and probably also what is your experience with handling them in your architecture.

Comment: Also there is "ASP.NET Membership" in 3.5 that has some facilities for dealing with this, but I don't know how programmer friendly it is.

Comment: A good question, which needs a better answer than those listed below.  I am looking at something similar in Java, but allowing inherited permissions.  I've had difficulty finding patterns/algorithms on the net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Users** and **Groups** with the ability to test `bool UserHasPermission( SOME_PERMISSION )` for an atomic permission associated with a Group is the standard approach for authorization, however things are changing to Claims-based:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163366.aspx

http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/10/Guide-Claim-Based-Identity

It however, is not ideal for all situations.

For the old model, I find that performance can be gained by using memoization during permissions checks.  That way I'm not going to the database n times per session to check access control.  Memoization effectively stores in a cache the result of a call with the same parameters, so all calls by a particular user to check XYZ permission would return the same result.  Of course, you'd make sure you stored the memoized permissions for the user in the Session so it's per-user.  If you load the permissions at login then you don't need to cache them, but in large systems with many permissions sometimes it's best to get them only when needed.

http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/01/CSharp-memory

Answer (score 8):

I've seen several complicated permission scheme. There was always a justification for it, but unfortunately, at a point in time, they all became too complicated to deal with and were reduced to something simpler.

My personal conclusion now is: stick to **Role base access control** ([RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)) this is the only reasonable one that everybody understands. It's somehow limited, but sufficient for most cases.

Also, use **deny by default** policy, that is, you grant rights only. Again, I've seen system with the opposite (allow by default) or even configurable default policy (!) and I don't think it reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I have not dealt with this from an application development standpoint, but often when dealing with permissions it is a good practice to set permissions for objects using roles, rather than giving users permission directly to the object.  If a user needs access to a particular set of objects, you don't give them access directly, you instead give them a role, which in turn has the needed access.  This in a way "reuses" the work that was put into creating the role.

Dealing with this in code however can get complicated, since you need to iterate through each of a user's roles and determine if the role gives the user permission to the object.  I don't know any specific suggestions on dealing with that other than the obvious of trying to factor that kind of code into its own framework.

Comment: Maybe there is no better way, that's basically the question ;) Actually we have these groups and roles concepts which make it very convenient for the end user which has various different ways of configuring permissions. The problem is more of a maintenance problem for us where managing all these different sources becomes more and more tedious.