# Design suggestions on Permission handling

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, asp.net-core, permissions

We have a rather complicated system for permissions at hour company for ASP.NET Core system we are running. So there are multiple applications and user's permission needs to carry over from one application to another so we are not creating a different permission table for each application for the user.

I found this from 8 years ago but since many new improvements made in this field, I wanted to bring it up to the table again.
[Patterns / design suggestions for permission handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337001/patterns-design-suggestions-for-permission-handling)

How is the best way to handle permissions through multiple apps that proves to have the least amount of extra data and efficient?

Comment: too broad with too little information

Comment: What other information needed?

Comment: what kind of permission? how are the permission relate to each other? are permissions for different app completely isolated from each other? whats the problem of storing all of them in one table? how many kinds of permissions do you anticipate? things like those

Comment: List of permission from ability to view, edit, add, delete to perform certain actions.Yes each app has its own isolated functions. There are so many attributes that needs to be allowed or not for each user. The problem is also, if we create a template and say each time we create a user we select a template to apply permissions, then at some point later we want to modify every xyz type of users we cant...

Comment: can you give some concrete example? still not convinced that group based policy wouldnt do the job

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but this may give you some ideas: https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/

Comment: @Steve group based policy would do the job but then I will need to make customizations and create a group for each then I will have 100s 1000s of groups...

Comment: Thank you @Ruard.